# Is Hasbrouck's information share measure a good indicator of whether a price leads others, and are there alternative indicators?

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

I meant the method in this paper: 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2329348

Comment: It is a measure of the influence of several trading venues on a SINGLE STOCK, not a measure of lead lag relations  BETWEEN STOCKS. Also, the trading environment has changed enormously since 1995.

Comment: @noob2 not sure, why do you think it matters.